# NFS mount timeout

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs

Like this, my server-side configure is `/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs 192.168.137.8(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)` in /etc/exports.

> [    4.995341] Root-NFS: nfsroot=/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs 
>   [    4.999167] NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=2,udp,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,nolock,addr=192.168.137.188' 
>       [    5.001094] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=2'
>       [    5.002329] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'udp'
>       [    5.002843] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'rsize=4096'
>       [    5.004294] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'wsize=4096'
>       [    5.004996] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'nolock'
>       [    5.005533] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=192.168.137.188'
>       [    5.008949] NFS: MNTPATH: '/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs'
>       [    5.010838] NFS: sending MNT request for 192.168.137.188:/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs
>       [    5.138789] NFS: MNT request succeeded
>       [    5.139382] NFS: Faking up auth_flavs list
>       [    5.144674] NFS: attempting to use auth flavor 1
>       [   10.357008] NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=2,udp,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,nolock,addr=192.168.137.188'
>       [   10.357996] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=2'
>       [   10.358620] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'udp'
>       [   10.359131] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'rsize=4096'
>       [   10.359734] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'wsize=4096'
>       [   10.360856] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'nolock'
>       [   10.361537] NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=192.168.137.188'
>       [   10.362440] NFS: MNTPATH: '/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs'
>       [   10.363178] NFS: sending MNT request for 192.168.137.188:/lenge/gnu/aarch64_sysroot_nfs
>       [   10.377199] NFS: MNT request succeeded
>       [   10.377666] NFS: Faking up auth_flavs list
>       [   10.378161] NFS: attempting to use auth flavor 1

So then, what is the problem？

Comment: Try to pass `nfsvers=3` to NFS parameters in kernel cmdline, I had similar issue and it helped me. I used [next U-Boot commands](https://pastebin.com/sh8dq59D) that worked fine for me. Other than that, the problem is most likely  with your host setup or cmdline, so this question doesn't belong to SO, try asking on ServerFault or SuperUser. Also, you should provide much more input, like kernel cmdline, your bootloader boot procedure/environenment (with NFS enabled), config files on your host, some related info from `/var/log/...` and `dmesg`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well. My /etc/exports looked like yours, but my problem was with my uEnv.txt, specifically how I was telling the kernel to mount the rootfs via NFS. See my image that summarizes the problem and solution.

[image: Problem & Solution]

In section 2 of the [nfsroot.txt](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/4.14/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt)
kernel doc for the BeagleBoneBlack it states that the NFS device and where to locate it need to be passed to the kernel in the following manner:

> `root=/dev/nfs`
>
> This is necessary to enable the pseudo-NFS-device. Note that it's not a
> real device but just a synonym to tell the kernel to use NFS instead of
> a real device.
>
> `nfsroot=[<server-ip>:]<root-dir>[,<nfs-options>]`
>
> If the `nfsroot' parameter is NOT given on the command line,
> the default "/tftpboot/%s" will be used.
>
> Specifies the IP address of the NFS server.
> The default address is determined by the `ip' parameter
> (see below). This parameter allows the use of different
> servers for IP autoconfiguration and NFS.
>
> Name of the directory on the server to mount as root.
> If there is a "%s" token in the string, it will be
> replaced by the ASCII-representation of the client's
> IP address.
>
> Standard NFS options. All options are separated by commas.
> The following defaults are used:
> port        = as given by server portmap daemon
> rsize       = 4096
> wsize       = 4096
> timeo       = 7
> retrans     = 3
> acregmin    = 3
> acregmax    = 60
> acdirmin    = 30
> acdirmax    = 60
> flags       = hard, nointr, noposix, cto, ac

I did add nfsvers=3 to my nfs-options as per @Sam Protsenko's suggestion, but I'm not sure if this alone or this combined with mentioned changes is what cause the kernel to mount the rootfs.

In my original uEnv.txt 'rootwait' & 'rootdelay=5' appear to be deprecated. NFS reported that those parameters were unrecognized when attempting to parse, so I removed them in my updated uEnv.txt.

If none of this doesn't help you, you can gather more information using the following:
[image: NFS debugging tools]

found [here](https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-set-up-and-configure-nfs-server-and-clients/)

Answer (score 0):

I to faced a similar kind of problem.  Once the correct nfs options are given the issue got solved.  The nfs options are documented in: [nfs options](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt).  This kernel documentation is not updated.  So to view the current set of options supported you can pass 'nfsrootdebug' in the kernel command line parameters.  This will list the current list of nfs options that are currently supported.  If this options is passed the kernel boot log will look like this:
[image: nfs options]

You choose the appropriate option from the list.